# What are the WordPress' pre-formatted html components?

Tags: html

There are html components or template parts (I don't know what's the most appropriate term) that WordPress preformatted, like *comments*, *comment-form*, *pagination*, *widgets*, and *navigation*.

Is there any article or documentation showing all of these? It would be a lot more efficient to be guided before front-end developing than hacking the defaults to accord it to finished html's.

I failed to search them, perhaps I don't have the best keyword. Or do I have to actually generate all of them in WordPress just to see the markup?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know any complete list but I know there are a lot more. For example, taxonomy term lists, navigation menus, prev/next post links,...... But I don't see any reason why knowing them before developing is more efficient. If you neeed one function that return formatted HTML, just use it and style it. In the case you need to customize the HTML, most of those functions have parameters that allow you to customize the output. I think that way is the same way you will do either if you know them before or after start developing.

Comment: I think it would be efficient, because if the front end developer were able to create the html's, exactly like how would functions output by default, the back-end developer wouldn't have to modify thru arguments and filters when using it in Wordpress, thus time and codes are saved.